# Tomcat is not starting sometimes in ubuntu14.04 through eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I am using tomcat server from eclipse for my projects. All these days it is working fine. But since 3 days tomcat is not starting sometimes from eclipse. I checked in Internet and tried lot many solutions. Even solutions given in other posts in stack-overflow related to this problem are not helping me. The console messages are

```
Oct 07, 2014 11:08:06 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/ packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
Oct 07, 2014 11:08:06 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:dims' did not find a matching property.
Oct 07, 2014 11:08:06 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:DReST' did not find a matching property.
Oct 07, 2014 11:08:06 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8181"]
Oct 07, 2014 11:08:06 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Oct 07, 2014 11:08:06 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 303 ms
Oct 07, 2014 11:08:06 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Oct 07, 2014 11:08:06 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.54
Oct 07, 2014 11:08:07 AM org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer init
INFO: Initializing Tiles2 container. . .
Oct 07, 2014 11:08:07 AM org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer initializeDefinitionsFactory
INFO: Tiles2 container initialization complete.
Oct 07, 2014 11:08:07 AM org.apache.tiles.access.TilesAccess setContainer
INFO: Publishing TilesContext for context: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade
Oct 07, 2014 11:08:07 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider info
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts-default.xml]
Oct 07, 2014 11:08:07 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider info
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts-plugin.xml]
Oct 07, 2014 11:08:07 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider info
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts.xml]
Oct 07, 2014 11:08:07 AM org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Loading global messages from ApplicationResources
Servlet Context --call back method--contextInitialized()
/home/saipavan/apache-tomcat-7.0.54/wtpwebapps/dims/StudentDao.properties
/home/saipavan/apache-tomcat-7.0.54/wtpwebapps/dims/
/home/saipavan/apache-tomcat-7.0.54/wtpwebapps/dims/
/home/saipavan/apache-tomcat-7.0.54/wtpwebapps/dims/
/home/saipavan/apache-tomcat-7.0.54/wtpwebapps/dims/
/home/saipavan/apache-tomcat-7.0.54/wtpwebapps/dims/
Oct 07, 2014 11:08:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/saipavan/apache-tomcat-7.0.54/webapps/manager
Oct 07, 2014 11:08:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /home/saipavan/apache-tomcat-7.0.54/webapps/manager has finished in 75 ms
Oct 07, 2014 11:08:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/saipavan/apache-tomcat-7.0.54/webapps/ROOT
Oct 07, 2014 11:08:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /home/saipavan/apache-tomcat-7.0.54/webapps/ROOT has finished in 67 ms
Oct 07, 2014 11:08:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/saipavan/apache-tomcat-7.0.54/webapps/host-manager
Oct 07, 2014 11:08:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /home/saipavan/apache-tomcat-7.0.54/webapps/host-manager has finished in 70 ms
Oct 07, 2014 11:08:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/saipavan/apache-tomcat-7.0.54/webapps/examples
Oct 07, 2014 11:08:09 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Oct 07, 2014 11:08:09 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Oct 07, 2014 11:08:09 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@7e7a19e7')
Oct 07, 2014 11:08:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /home/saipavan/apache-tomcat-7.0.54/webapps/examples has finished in 142 ms
Oct 07, 2014 11:08:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/saipavan/apache-tomcat-7.0.54/webapps/docs
Oct 07, 2014 11:08:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /home/saipavan/apache-tomcat-7.0.54/webapps/docs has finished in 68 ms
Oct 07, 2014 11:08:09 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8181"]
Oct 07, 2014 11:08:09 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Oct 07, 2014 11:08:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2670 ms
```

I am able to start tomcat through terminal. but when i try to open tomcat in browser after starting, I am getting error

```
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost:8181.
```

What might be the problem? Can anyone help me? Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

seems localhost is not getting resolved to IP address. Try to ping localhost `ping -c localhost` or try  your systems IP address instead of localhost.

Comment: $ ping localhost<br/>
`PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.<br/>
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.028 ms<br/>
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.032 ms<br/>
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.021 ms<br/>
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.013 ms` <br/><br/>

$ ping -c localhost<br/>
`ping: bad number of packets to transmit.`